# react-native-picker-select is closing on value change in iOS

Tags: react-native, picker

I am using this library for react-native picker but it is not working as expected. Library link - https://github.com/markuswind/react-native-select-input-ios
picker is closing it self while changing it's value.

```
<SelectInput
                style={styles.picker}
                value={ounitr}
                options={unit}
/>
```

I am using above code for picker where unit is defined

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      unit: [
        {label: 'mm', value: 'mm'},
        {label: 'cm', value: 'cm'},
        {label: 'meters', value: 'm'},
        {label: 'km', value: 'km'},
        {label: 'inches', value: 'in'},
        {label: 'feet', value: 'ft'},
        {label: 'yards', value: 'yd'},
        {label: 'miles', value: 'mi'},
        {label: 'nautical miles', value: 'nmi'},
      ],
      scaler: 1,
      scales: 12,
      oscaler: 1,
      oscales: 12,
      olengthr: 120,
      olengths: 10,
      ounitr: 'mm',
      ounits: 'mm',
      formula: '',
    };
    this.setOunitrValue = this.setOunitrValue.bind(this);
    this.setOunitsValue = this.setOunitsValue.bind(this);
  }
```

[image: vyBx8olr8s]

Comment: If you put a try/catch on the render function, it returns an error?

Comment: i am new to react native can you please show me how I can do this ?

Comment: something like this: 
render() {
  try {
    return (
      //your render here
    )
  } catch(error){
    alert(error)
  }
}

A comment doesnt work pretty well with identation but  i hope you understand it.

Comment: there is nothing in catch any other idea ?